# Then problem about jquery dialog ui and html() ,text() function

Tags: html, jquery-ui, text, dialog

I have a jquery ui dialog with a textarea in it :

```
<div id="dialog">
     <textarea id="box">Hello World</textarea>
</div>
```

Once I open the dialog ,I could edit the textarea's content,

then when close the dialog,I want get the content that I have edited

```
the dialog code:
 $("#dialog").dialog({
                 autoOpen: false,
                 height: 140,
                 buttons: {
                     Confirm: function () {
                         alert($('#box').html());
                         $(this).dialog("close");
                     }
                 }
             });
```

In this example,the original content is "hello world",then the dialog open,I delete the "world", the strange thing is that,when I click confirm,the page alert still "hello world"

I change html() function to text(),the result still the same,so how can I get the content that I edited when close the dialog?

PS:the reason I use Html() is that I want the content write to Sql database ,keep the `"<br>"` or `"＆nbsp;"`

[the online example is here](http://jsfiddle.net/Xu35D/)

Answer (score 3):

Try using:

```
$("#box").val()
```

instead of:

```
$("#box").html()
```

If you need to have `<br>`s for newlines, you can do replacements such as:

```
$("#box").val().replace(/\n/g, "<br>")
```